# iPhone sdk location change notification

Tags: iphone

I am planning to do GPS location on iPhone. Can you tell me the information regarding GPS (delegates,methods etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a Location Manager of CLLocation

```
CLLocationManager *locManager;
```

In your Function

```
self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
locManager.delegate = self; 
locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locManager startUpdatingLocation];   // This Method will call the didUpdateToLocation Delegate
[locManager stopUpdatingLocation];   //This Methods stops the GPS from updating
```

Location Manager Delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 //Do actions when the GPS is Updating
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error in GPS: %@",error);  
}
```

Dont forget to include CLLocationManagerDelegate in .h file and Add CoreLocation Framework to your project

Answer (score 3):

Look up the documentation for `CLLocationManager` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. If you still have specific questions then, come back and ask them.